# Likelihood of a human name being last name given two first and last name sets that intersect

Tags: probability

We have two lists, one being human first M and the other last N names all unique. Let's consider these lists exhaustive with unknown name frequencies. The lists overlap (meaning that some last names can be first as well) and this intersection has K names.
We observe a name which is in the intersection. What is the the likelihood that this will be e.g. a last name?
Will Bayesian inference apply or I'm overcomplicating?

Comment: Draw the Venn diagram: that virtually answers the question.

Comment: yeah thanks it does. the simplest way

Answer (score 1):

actually this is incomplete, one has to consider frequencies each name has in population. Let given name be encountered as first name be Ffn and as the last name - Fln. Then it is pretty obvious that probability of encountering given name as a last name will be Fln / (Ffn + Fln).  The Bayes rule yields the same equation.